# What would be done if a machine went haywire and all the scientists died?

Tags: science-fiction, military, conspiracy

Not sure how to word the title. In my story a piece of secret US technology was being tested in the congo, but it ended up exploding and causing a temporal anomaly that send anyone within its radius to be zipped out of existence, though it superficially appears to be normal.

They have lost communication.

This, I assume, would be covered up, but what exactly would the procedure be here? What kind of people would be sent to deal with this? Military personnel? Peacekeepers?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Sounds like a job for The Doctor, but you don't want to tread on BBC's toes...

Comment: SCP Foundation Mobile Task Force.

Comment: @Jobah_HigherMind LOL

Comment: @ZeissIkon LMAO

Comment: This does not sound like a worldbuilding question. It sounds like a question about a story. Those kinds of questions depend to get closed.

Comment: @Daron doesn't matter tbh, I got my answers.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of your question sounds rather far-fetched, so answers are a bit difficult.

- The US running something like this in the Congo sounds like a bad novel or a bad conspiracy theory. If it isn't save to tuck the lab away in [Nevada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevada_Test_and_Training_Range), going over the Atlantic won't help, either. So maybe the lab belongs to somebody **other than the government**, who needs to evade government oversight?
- Sending in [UN Peacekeepers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_Nations_peacekeeping_missions) is extremely unlikely. Somebody would have to explain to the UN and other nations **why** peacekeepers are required. They usually go to keep two fighting sides apart, with the consent of both sides. That means there would have been a conflict, but then why hide a secret lab there?
- Somewhat unlikely that everybody who understands the experiments is on site when it happens. Nobody at headquarters who understands what is going on? Nobody away sick? Nobody on leave?

So decide how you want to build your story. Some US government site in the continental US? Some shadowy fictional conspiracy, in Congo? Why would the US government get involved in the cover-up, if it wasn't in the US?

Comment: Okay so I like the shadowy conspiracy, I said the US because I wanted to connect it to the Philadelphia experiments, but I guess continued research could be outlawed and then the scientists wants to keep working? In that case who would be sent?

Comment: @user8796978 probably the forces of whatever congolese warlord is in the area

Comment: @user8796978, if there was a secret corporate lab and the US government finds out and investigates, the forces would be a balance of secrecy and speed. The fastest option is problably to drop a company or battalion of the 82nd airborne, directly from the US, ignoring the need to get overflight rights from African countries. (What can they do, shoot them down? With what?) A slower and much more secret approach would use a private military company with ties to the CIA, with less Congressional oversight.

Answer (score 3):

Whoever is running this (government, shadow organization etc) would send their teams of agents first.

If this event is a visible accident, local authorities would send their own resources too.

If this event looks like a global disaster, then (and only then) global organizations like United Nations may get involved, and it will be slower response that the first two players.

P.S. This question looks like a story set in the real world rather that about building a world, so I am not sure I should even be answering it.